# Angular Compile Error: Type Subscription is Missing the Following Properties from Type Object[]: length, pop, push, concat

Tags: angular

I have been trying to figure out this for long time without any success.
Would appreciate some help !
I am using Angular Version 13,  & trying to perform get request to get objects array from the database.
I am getting the error: Type "Subscription" is missing the following properties from type 'Object[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.

app.components.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { SEOService } from './services/shared/seo.service';
    import { StartupService } from './services/shared/startup.service';
    import { Object } from './services/shared/object';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
      siteUrl: string;
      pageObjects: Object[];
      pageConfig: any;
    
      constructor(private startupService: StartupService, private seoService: SEOService){
        this.siteUrl = '';
        this.pageObjects = [];
        this.pageConfig = {};
      };
    
      ngOnInit(){
        this.siteUrl = window.location.href;
        this.pageConfig = this.startupService.getPageConfig(this.siteUrl);    
        this.seoService.updateTitle(this.pageConfig.title);
        this.seoService.updateDescription(this.pageConfig.description);    

        this.pageObjects = this.startupService.getPageObjects(1).subscribe(
      (response: Object[]) => {
        this.pageObjects = response;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
      };
    };
```

startup.service.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Object } from './object';
    
    @Injectable()
    
    export class StartupService {
      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){};
    
      getPageConfig(requestUrl: string): any[]{
        var pageConfig: any = {
          type: 'webproject',
          title: 'Yellow Pages & Classifieds',
          description: 'Yellow Pages & Classifieds'
        };
        return pageConfig;
      };
    
      getPageObjects(pageNID: number): Observable<Object[]>{
        return this.httpClient.get<Object[]>('http://localhost:1040/objects/getallbypage/' + pageNID);
      }
    };
```

object.ts

```js
    export class Object {
        _id: string;
        nid: number;
        id: string;
        title: string;
        type: string;
        path: string;
        ofnid: number;
        of: string;
        loadpriority: number;
        isactive: boolean;
        pagenid: number;
        
        constructor(){
            this._id = '';
            this.nid = 0;
            this.id = '';
            this.title = '';
            this.type = '';
            this.path = '';
            this.ofnid = 0;
            this.of = '';
            this.loadpriority = 0;
            this.isactive = true;
            this.pagenid = 0;
        };
    };
```

Comment: You are assigning an Observable subscription to a property of type array, that's what the error tells you, and that results in the type error you are seeing.

Comment: Thx for the response... Appreciate if you can recommend correction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a silly mistake, you don't need this extra assignment here:

```js
this.pageObjects = this.startupService.getPageObjects(1).subscribe(
...
)
```

Change to

```js
this.startupService.getPageObjects(1).subscribe(
...
)
```

It's worth mentioning that the return value of `Observable.subscribe()` is of type `Subscription`. Holding on to it lets you unsubscribe, which is necessary for subscriptions that never stop emitting values. You don't need to worry about it when making simple HTTP requests using the `HTTPClient` service since they only emit one value and then clean themselves up.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the `pageObjects` property to the actual observable, and then reassigning the same property to the response of that observable.

You are interested in the results of the subscription, so just get rid of the part where you assign `pageObjects` to the observable.

```
this.startupService.getPageObjects(1).subscribe(
  (response: Object[]) => {
    this.pageObjects = response;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately mate I'm a bit new to Angular. Appreciate if you can expand on above. Exactly what do I need to change in above code?

Comment: Replace the block that starts with `this.pageObjects = this.startupService.getP.....` with the above snippet.

So instead of assigning `this.pageObjects` to an observable, you are now  subscribing to the observable and then you assign `this.pageObjects` to the result you receive from the emitted value from the observable,